# Can't use \newpage

Tags: landscape

I'm a total noob on latex, I am trying to make a landscape document, nothing too fancy, I just need to create multiple landscape pages with text that has some very specific position in each page (the text is the same for every page), until I only have one page everything works, but when I try to use \newpage, even tought it still compiles, the second page doesn't show up, I probably messed something up in the code but as I said, I'm a total noob and I can't understand where, any help would be appreciated :D

This is the code,

```
    % !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
    % !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

    % This is a simple template for a LaTeX document using the "article" class.
    % See "book", "report", "letter" for other types of document.

    \documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

    \usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)


    %%% Examples of Article customizations
    % These packages are optional, depending whether you want the features they provide.
    % See the LaTeX Companion or other references for full information.

    %%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
    \usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
    \geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....
    \geometry{bottom=0.1in,top=0.1in,left=0.7in,right=0.7in} % for example, change the margins to 2 inches all round
    % \geometry{landscape} % set up the page for landscape
    %   read geometry.pdf for detailed page layout information

    \usepackage{graphicx} % support the \includegraphics command and options

    % \usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent

    %%% PACKAGES
    \usepackage{booktabs} % for much better looking tables
    \usepackage{array} % for better arrays (eg matrices) in maths
    \usepackage{paralist} % very flexible & customisable lists (eg. enumerate/itemize, etc.)
    \usepackage{verbatim} % adds environment for commenting out blocks of text & for better verbatim
    \usepackage{subfig} % make it possible to include more than one captioned figure/table in a single float
    % These packages are all incorporated in the memoir class to one degree or another...

    %%% HEADERS & FOOTERS
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} % This should be set AFTER setting up the page geometry
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \pagestyle{empty} % options: empty , plain , fancy
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % customise the layout...
    \lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
    \lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage}\rfoot{}

    %%% SECTION TITLE APPEARANCE
    \usepackage{sectsty}
    \allsectionsfont{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape} % (See the fntguide.pdf for font help)
    % (This matches ConTeXt defaults)

    %%% ToC (table of contents) APPEARANCE
    \usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} % Put the bibliography in the ToC
    \usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft} % Alter the style of the Table of Contents
    \renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape}
    \renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape} % No bold!

    %%% END Article customizations

    %%% The "real" document content comes below...

    %\title{Brief Article}
    %\author{The Author}
    %\date{} % Activate to display a given date or no date (if empty),
             % otherwise the current date is printed 


    \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

    \begin{document}


    \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(16cm,1.8cm) % {block width} (coords) 
       Nome Evento
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(13cm,2.7cm) % {block width} (coords) 
       Giorno
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(9cm,3.8cm) % {block width} (coords) 
      Razza
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(9cm,5cm) % {block width} (coords) 
      Loi
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(16cm,5cm) % {block width} (coords) 
       Codice Identificativo
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(24cm,5cm) % {block width} (coords) 
       Sesso
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(9.5cm,19.9cm) % {block width} (coords) 
       Giudice
    \end{textblock*}


    \newpage %%%% NOT WORKING FOR SOME REASON

    \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(16cm,1.8cm) % {block width} (coords) 
       Nome Evento
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(13cm,2.7cm) % {block width} (coords) 
       Giorno
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(9cm,3.8cm) % {block width} (coords) 
      Razza
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(9cm,5cm) % {block width} (coords) 
      Loi
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(16cm,5cm) % {block width} (coords) 
       Codice Identificativo
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(24cm,5cm) % {block width} (coords) 
       Sesso
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(9.5cm,19.9cm) % {block width} (coords) 
       Giudice
    \end{textblock*}

    \end{document}
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by minimizing your code example (e.g. remove doubled package inclusions like `geometry`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those `textblock`s are being typeset in the "background" (of sorts) and this does not add any material to the real page. So when `\newpage` comes along and forces latex to ship the page, there is nothing real to ship out, and `\newpage` is ignored.

Try simply adding a `\strut` as in

```
\strut\newpage
```

A strut is an invisible vertical line, but now there *is* something real, and `\newpage` can ship out the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot man you saved me, anyway about the pdfpages tag, I didn't think this was a library (or isn't it?), tought this could somehow be related to the pages :D

Comment: @Maxpnl `pdfpages` is a LaTeX package to include full pdf files (each page in the PDF replaces a page in the document), thus the confusion related to your question.